# Linq greater than or less than equivalent

Tags: c#, linq

In SQL the following query returns 18 records as expected.

```
select * from BomTransAction
where Quantity <> QauntityToTransfer
```

However, in Linq I can't use this function.  Can someone tell me what the equivalent Linq functions are for less than or greater than? ie. the symbol <>.

Also, I am wondering if I will have to do two operations here in this instance?

```
bomsRefresh.Where(w => w.QauntityToTransfer  <> w.Quantity).ToList();
```

Comment: Are either of the columns nullable?

Answer (score 5):

In SQL the <> means "not equal to".

```
select * from BomTransAction where Quantity <> QuantityToTransfer
```

means "Select all from BomTransferAction where Quantity is not equal to QuantityToTransfer".

In Linq, it would be:

```
bomRefresh.Where(w => w.QuantityToTransfer != w.Quantity).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for values less than or greater than, you are basically looking for any value that is not w.Quantity. So you could use not equal to, which is '!='

Answer (score -2):

Try your sql query using **!=** rather than **<>**

```
select * from BomTransAction
where Quantity != QauntityToTransfer
```

The result should be the same. Because in sql **<>** is basically a not equal operation.

Then in linq, you can use **!=** but not **<>**